# Sitecore custom dialog application remains empty

Tags: xaml, sitecore, sitecore6

So I've created a small custom dialog application for sitecore that is called through a ribbon button which triggers a command which in turn triggers my custom control.

My command (which works in triggering the open dialog trigger):

```
var uri = UIUtil.GetUri("control:LanguageCopyModule");
var id = context.Items[0].ID.ToString();
var la = context.Items[0].Language;
var url = string.Format("{0}&id={1}&la={2}", uri, id, la.Name);
SheerResponse.ShowModalDialog(url);
```

The URL it generates in a popup window:

[http://mydomain/sitecore/shell/default.aspx?xmlcontrol=LanguageCopyModule&id={E67AD356-3999-4D4C-ACE4-C570EFD1FBE0}&la=en](http://mydomain/sitecore/shell/default.aspx?xmlcontrol=LanguageCopyModule&id=%7BE67AD356-3999-4D4C-ACE4-C570EFD1FBE0%7D&la=en)

Untill this point it all works prefectly, but now when it opens my xml control window it just stays empty.

This is the code  behind the xml:

```
<control xmlns:def="Definition" xmlns="http://schemas.sitecore.net/Visual-Studio-Intellisense">
  <LanguageCopyModule>
    <FormDialog Icon="Applications/16x16/paste.png" Header="Language Copy Module" Text="Copy field values between different languages." OKButton="Copy" CancelButton="Cancel">
      <CodeBeside Type="MyAssembly.Modules.LanguageCopyModule.LanguageCopyModule,MyAssembly.Modules"/>
      <GridPanel Columns="2">
        <GridPanel.ColumnStyles>
          <Column Width="70%" />
          <Column Width="30%" />
        </GridPanel.ColumnStyles>

        <GridPanel.RowStyles>
          <Row Height="100%" />
        </GridPanel.RowStyles>

        <!-- Fields -->
        <FlowPanel>
          <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="black">
            <Text>Text</Text>
          </Border>
        </FlowPanel>

        <!-- Languages -->
        <FlowPanel>
          <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="black">
            <Button>Button</Button>
          </Border>
        </FlowPanel>
      </GridPanel>

    </FormDialog>
  </LanguageCopyModule>
</control>
```

Any ideas as to why it remains empty? There's little documentation to be found and it could be I just missed something.

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: I have found the issue: the .xml file NEEDS to be somewhere under /sitecore/shell in your filesystem.

Comment: You should answer your question and accept your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the issue: the .xml file NEEDS to be somewhere under /sitecore/shell in your filesystem.

Answer (score 7):

This is regulated by the `<controlSources>` element in web.config. You can either put your XML control to any of the folders mentioned there, or add another control source. Note that there's a special "override" folder foreseen for such purpose. If you still need to add your own control source, remember that from Sitecore 6.0 it can be done in a pluggable configs (there's official Sitecore doc on this plus several blog posts out there).

Comment: Yan, I cannot express how grateful I am for your answer.

Comment: So to be specific, add something like this to <controlSources> in web.config: <source mode="on" namespace="Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls" folder="/your/relative/path/to/the/control" deep="true"/>